# Java Image byte array size

Tags: java, arrays, image

I am trying to print bitmap image. In order to print image my printer needs byte array of bitmap. Picture size is 128x128 pixel.

Here is code how I read and convert image to byte array.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("test.bmp"));
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image, "bmp", baos);
byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
System.out.println(imageInByte.length);
```

After code execution **imageInByte** array length is 2110. What am I missing here? Should not array length be 16384 (128 x 128)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming one byte per pixel and no header information. The "bitsPerPixel" header will play a large part in determining how much space the image data takes up. See the structure of a bitmap file [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#/media/File:BMPfileFormat.png).